# 'Instant preview' suddenly stopped in a LyX document

Tags: lyx

I'm working on a fairly large LyX document. So far, `instant preview` has worked perfectly. Recently my document stopped loading instant previews when it's opened, although it does load instant previews for *newly added* text.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Works well for me on Ubuntu with LyX 2.3.1. What OS are you using? What LyX version?

Comment: @scottkosty I'm using LyX 2.2.3 on Windows 10.

Comment: If this issue is important to you, you might consider trying LyX 2.3.2 when it comes out (in a couple of weeks). I don't remember a specific fix for what you describe, but there have been a lot of fixes since 2.2.3. Only switch to a different "major version" (2.3.x) if you have time to deal with any big changes though, and always back up all of your documents.